# How to save an image to the media provider in Android?

Tags: android

I used this code [snippet](http://snipplr.com/view/13772/save-image-to-media-provider-on-android/):

```
ContentValues image = new ContentValues();

image.put(Images.Media.TITLE, "ImageTitle");
image.put(Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, "Heart");
image.put(Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "Heart");
image.put(Images.Media.DATE_ADDED, dateTaken);
image.put(Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, dateTaken);
image.put(Images.Media.DATE_MODIFIED, dateTaken);
image.put(Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/png");
image.put(Images.Media.ORIENTATION, 0);

File parent = imageFile.getParentFile();
String path = parent.toString().toLowerCase();
String name = parent.getName().toLowerCase();
image.put(Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_ID, path.hashCode());
image.put(Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME, name);
image.put(Images.Media.SIZE, imageFile.length());

image.put("_data", imageFile.getAbsolutePath());

getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, image);
```

I create the image inside the cache directory of my application. I assume that the image is not copied into the media folder by the media provider and therefore not accessible from the media gallery application. Is it possible to add an image to the media gallery without writing the file to the mass storage of the phone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the answer you are looking for is described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html#modifying).  The second part of that section describes saving images.  The gist of it appears to be that you first insert the ContentValues object into the content resolver, which returns a Uri object that the ContentResolver is willing to turn into an OutputStream for you that you can write the image to.  The link provided includes the actual code you would need to do that.